# "Authentication failed! Invalid username or password when running" in .jsp IntelliJ

Tags: java, tomcat, server

"Application Server was not connected before run configuration stop, reason:
                com.intellij.javaee.oss.admin.jmx.JmxAdminException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.SecurityException: Authentication failed! Invalid username or password"

Thats what I get when I run my .jsp file. I'm logged into IntelliJ.

```
pom.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>org.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>ultTest</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <name>ultTest Maven Webapp</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>


  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>ultTest</finalName>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- see http://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_war_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.2.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

```
ultTest.iml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module type="JAVA_MODULE" version="4" />
```

```
index.jsp:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h2>Hello World!</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

```
web.xml:
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
</web-app>
```

```
server output:
/Users/nathanadavis/Desktop/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh run
[2020-03-24 04:43:40,658] Artifact ultTest:war exploded: Waiting for server connection to start artifact deployment...
NOTE: Picked up JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS:  --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
Error: Exception thrown by the agent : java.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in use: 1099; nested exception is: 
    java.net.BindException: Address already in use
jdk.internal.agent.AgentConfigurationError: java.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in use: 1099; nested exception is: 
    java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at jdk.management.agent/sun.management.jmxremote.ConnectorBootstrap.startRemoteConnectorServer(ConnectorBootstrap.java:491)
    at jdk.management.agent/jdk.internal.agent.Agent.startAgent(Agent.java:447)
    at jdk.management.agent/jdk.internal.agent.Agent.startAgent(Agent.java:599)
Caused by: java.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in use: 1099; nested exception is: 
    java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.listen(TCPTransport.java:335)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.exportObject(TCPTransport.java:243)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.exportObject(TCPEndpoint.java:412)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.LiveRef.exportObject(LiveRef.java:147)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.exportObject(UnicastServerRef.java:234)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl.setup(RegistryImpl.java:220)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl.<init>(RegistryImpl.java:180)
    at jdk.management.agent/sun.management.jmxremote.SingleEntryRegistry.<init>(SingleEntryRegistry.java:49)
    at jdk.management.agent/sun.management.jmxremote.ConnectorBootstrap.exportMBeanServer(ConnectorBootstrap.java:836)
    at jdk.management.agent/sun.management.jmxremote.ConnectorBootstrap.startRemoteConnectorServer(ConnectorBootstrap.java:479)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:469)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:458)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.bind(NioSocketImpl.java:643)
    at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:374)
    at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:260)
    at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:151)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPDirectSocketFactory.createServerSocket(TCPDirectSocketFactory.java:45)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newServerSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:670)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.listen(TCPTransport.java:324)
    ... 11 more
Disconnected from server
```

Comment: The cause of the exception is stating `Port already in use: 1099`. try some higher port number like 8080 or beyond

Comment: Changed my JMX port to 8080 and its not giving me that exception anymore but a new one: "Application Server was not connected before run configuration stop, reason:
    java.io.IOException: Failed to retrieve RMIServer stub: javax.naming.CommunicationException [Root exception is java.rmi.ConnectIOException: non-JRMP server at remote endpoint]" Also my directory for apache is valid, no backlashes. So it's not that

Comment: Ah just changed port number again, worked. Only problem is now safari, firefox won't open the page...

Comment: The JMX/RMI port and the HTTP port are two different ports. The default for the JMX/RMI port is 1099, but it seems you have already something else using that port.
The HTTP port is 8080 by default for tomcat, that's the port your browser should use, no need to change that.

Comment: I got everything working, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I got the error, running the command below resolved the issue;

```
$ catalina stop --force
```

and press `Run` [image] `button` which is on the toolbar.

I hope that process can help you.